# Random div position in fixed size frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have fixed size frame, in this frame there are some images with different size, it looks like this:

[image: my-div]

I want to show the images randomly or not in order.

Comment: I think you need to consider the resolution of the images also in different div

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an image that covers the whole surface of the container you can use the css3 function `cover`.

Here an example: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/#article-header-id-0

Here the official documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp